# Curl receives empty repsonse form Elasticsearch server

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a healthy ES cluster running on ec2.  I'm tyring to connect Graylog server to the cluster using unicast, but Graylog receives an empty reponse from the unicast host.  Using curl, I can reproduce the empty response.

The result of 
    curl 10.10.198.233:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true

is

```
"cluster_name" : "graylog-graylog-elasticsearch-scratch-Scratch-client-0otqGLpa",
"status" : "green",
"timed_out" : false,
"number_of_nodes" : 3,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
"active_primary_shards" : 1,
"active_shards" : 2,
"relocating_shards" : 0,
"initializing_shards" : 0,
"unassigned_shards" : 0,
"number_of_pending_tasks" : 0
}
```

The result of 
    curl 10.10.198.233:9300

gives
    curl: (52) Empty reply from server

This is causing Graylog server to fail at startup.  How do I fix the empty response given by the Elasticsearch node?